# How can i add a property to an inner Object in Typescript with spread operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, spread

I have following Object

```
let car = { year: 2004, type: {name: "BMW"} }
```

Now i want to add a property to inner object "type". I want to to this with the spread operator, since i need a new object, because the existing is an immuteable state object. The result should be:

```
{ year: 2004, type: {name: "BMW", modell: "3er"}}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const car = { year: 2004, type: {name: "BMW"} };
const modifiedCar = {...car, type: {...car.type, modell: "3er"}};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

(Not Immutable)

```js
let car = { year: 2004, type: {name: "BMW"} } // changed
Object.assign(car.type, {modell: "3er"});

console.log(car)
```

(Immutable)

```js
let car = { year: 2004, type: {name: "BMW"} } // still the same
const result = Object.assign({}, car, {type:{...car.type, modell: "3er"}});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another variable to this object which as you can see is deeply nested.

```
const functionParams = {
    handler,
    runtime,
    environment: {
        variables: {
            restrictedActions: config.restrictedActions
        }
    }
}
```

I achieved it like so:

```
const newFunctionParams = {...functionParams, environment: {
    ...functionParams.environment, variables: {
        ...functionParams.environment.variables,
            APIAllowEndpoint: `https://severless....`,
            APIDenyEndpoint: `https://severless....`,
            TOPIC: topicArn
    }
}}
```

The result:

```
{
    handler,
    runtime,
    environment: {
        variables: {
            restrictedActions: config.restrictedActions,
            APIAllowEndpoint: `https://severless....`,
            APIDenyEndpoint: `https://severless....`,
            TOPIC: topicArn
        }
    }
}
```

Credit to @chelmertz